# Latex on Individual User Profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, formatting, profile-page

I'm wondering that if we are allowed to use the Latex Typesetting Language on our individual user profiles since it sounds quite fun actually? :)

Comment: Given that using LaTeX works in the bio section of the profile page, I see no reason not to do it. It might not work on the mini-bio popups, though, but I haven't checked this.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. :) I just like so much playing and having some experience with Latex, that's why also... :) Latex makes people like Maths and related fields...